# Python - Matplotlib - Keep axes even and linear and have points plotted on grid

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, grid

So, I've scoured the internet for a **long** time and come up with nothing.

Suppose I have this:

```
x = [35,86,34,55]
y = [11,84,73,26]

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

This is a simplified version (without adding titles etc.)

I want to know how I can create a grid with points (not connected) at certain co-ordinates. Easy enough. But I would like the grid axes to be even. So, rather than the x-axis progressing as 35, 86, 34, 55, it would progress from 1 to 100 and those x-axis points would be plotted on the grid. I have tried the following:

```
plt.xlim()
# and
plt.axis('equal')
```

and I have come up with no results.

The resulting graph consists of a 45* line with and x- and y-axis non-linear. Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Thanks, Reece

Comment: So you need the x axis from 1 to 100 but the grid lines should pass only through the 4 data points horizontally and vertically? Your desired output is unclear right now

Comment: I would like it to work like a map, in a way. So, 1-100 on the x and y axes and then 4 points such as (25,74) (45,73) (63,90) (4,7) etc.

Comment: "I would like it to work like a map, in a way. ". This isn't helping. It will be helpful for readers and probably the best way to avoid unnecessary questions to you from people who want to provide answers if you add some sample plot to your question. Even a hand drawn sketch would help. Otherwise, it's just unnecessary work from both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from your question and comments what your final figure should look like. Based on my interpretation of your words, you want the grid lines to pass through only the specified data points. To do so, you need to first set the x- and y-ticks at those coordinate positions and then turn the grid on.

```
x = [25,45,63,4]
y = [74,73,90,7]

plt.plot(x,y, 'ko')
plt.xlim(0, 100)
plt.xticks(x)
plt.yticks(y)
plt.grid()
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, if I was unclear, but this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.